# How to access Object Events of Powerpoint(Mac Version) using Apple script?

Tags: vba, macos, applescript, ms-office, powerpoint

I want to add a call back function to identify the Save action in Powerpoint.
Using VBA we can execute this scenario using Application.PresentationSave Event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744230.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

During the research I found that Application Object events not enabled or not supported in Powerpoint mac version.
(http://youpresent.co.uk/powerpoint-application-events-in-vba/)

Is there any way to achieve this scenario using apple script.

Scenario:
I want to check that which slides are modified while user pressing save button in powerpoint. So If I can use ApplicationSave event, I will compare modified slide with master slide when user press save button.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is not possible from this answer on ExpertsExchange:

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28660552/VBA-application-events-or-equivalent-for-PowerPoint-mac-2011.html